# Svelte and Rollup: How to export components which can be fetched via AJAX, cached, and reused on multiple pages?

Tags: rollupjs, svelte

In my Svelte + Rollup project `src` folder I have two subfolders, `components` and `pages`. Let me describe my dream, and hopefully somebody can shed some light on whether it's possible.

1. The components and pages are exported as their own files (I have that working via [rollup-plugin-multi-input](https://github.com/alfredosalzillo/rollup-plugin-multi-input)).
2. When a page is hit, it requests all the components it needs.
3. The component JS files are then cached. All future page calls that need the same components draw from the cache.

Is this reasonable, or would it be better to just export the pages individually and bundle the components into each page, duplicating code?

#### Another potential idea

Do an `App.svelte` file that imports all the components, aggregate those into an object, pass that object into the page component as a prop, then do `<svelte:component this={components.Input}>` for all components inside the page.

```js
App.svelte:

<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import Input from 'Input.svelte';
  import Popup from 'Popup.svelte';
  const components = {Input, Popup};
  let page;
  function getPage(url) {
    /* AJAX call to fetch the page component and set it to the page variable */
  }
  onMount(() => getPage(location.pathname))
</script>

<svelte:component this={page} components>
```

```js
Page1.svelte:

<script>
  export let components;
</script>

<p>Type your name:</p>
<svelte:component this={components.Input}>
```

With this method, all the components are included in the bundle even if the user never hits a page that contains some of those.

Comment: Have you considered using SvelteKit? You can create an endpoint under routes that allowes you to export components and send response so you can use wherever you want. Have a look at this post if that helps you. With this approach, you won't have to cache any components. Just call the endpoint wherever you need it. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67941692/call-component-from-one-sveltekit-app-to-another-sveltekit-app

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are talking about some sort of elaborate, manual code-splitting.

When you build a Svelte/Sapper project with Rollup, it will bundle and chunk your components, routes, etc, into a series of smaller chunks of JS, which are loaded only when required, saving bandwidth and increasing speed. You don't need the multi-input plugin for this.

Also note that your plan of loading components via AJAX won't work, since Svelte is a compiled language, and won't build and assign things on the fly in a user's browser.

Out of curiosity, what is the bundle size you are struggling with? Svelte already makes some of the tiniest bundles of any frontend framework, so what are you doing to give you size concerns?

Comment: I should specify, I do not have access to Sapper for this. I have to make it work with an Apache + Tomcat + Java backend. Although perhaps I could use Sapper+Polka and bypass Tomcat? I'll have to look into that. I think our team would prefer not to be running both a Java and a Node server though.

Comment: Yeah - if your constraint is that you can't use Sapper for SSR, then you would probably have to roll all the good stuff that Sapper does in Java + Tomcat, and then hydrate that output on the client.

Though to be honest at this point I'd ask your team why running a node server for the explicit purpose of SSR is less appealing than having to rebuild part of a framework in Java! Node is the right tool for the task in this instance, so I guess it's probably worth doing some sessions on why that is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll take this into consideration :)